# WPallimport function to create user from csv column

Tags: php, wordpress, function, buddypress, wpallimport

My goal is to import a csv file with houses for sale and generate realtors as wordpress/buddypress user if they don't exist yet. I want to do so by using a custom function in WP all import. Addtitionally i would like to set the buddypress membertype to "realtor" for internal user

I will map the source field to a custom field in the import config
 `[create_realtor{realtor_column}]`

in my case that is `[create_realtor{properties[1]/property[2]/value[1]}]`

As it is a user for internal purposes, i don't need the actual realtor contact details, so the user email will be realtor@mydomain.com, pass can generated, email to realtor not needed.

I found that a user can be generated as below [source](https://tommcfarlin.com/create-a-user-in-wordpress/):

```
if( null == username_exists( $email_address ) ) {

  // Generate the password and create the user
  $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $email_address, $password, $email_address );
 
  // Set the nickname
  wp_update_user(
    array(
     'ID'          =>    $user_id,
     'nickname'    =>    $email_address  
    )
  );

 
  // Set the role
  $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
  $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );
 
 
} // end if
```

How can i wrap all in a function that will generate the user based on the realtor name in my feed
would it be like below?

```
function create_realtor($realtor) {

$emailadress = $realtor . '@mydomain.com' ;

if( null == username_exists( $email_address ) ) {

  // Generate the password and create the user
  $password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $email_address, $password, $email_address );
 
  // Set the nickname
  wp_update_user(
    array(
     'ID'          =>    $user_id,
     'nicename'    =>    $nicename,  //realtor
     'nickname'    =>    $email_address  //realtor@mydomain.com
    )
  );

 

  // Set the role
  $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
  $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );

// Set the member type of user to 'realtor'.
$member_type = bp_set_member_type( $user_id, 'realtor' );
 
 
} // end if




}
```

I tried above, but it results in a message saying "Custom Field Value template is invalid: Unexpected token XPATH, statement was expected."

I am a bit lost here on how to procede

Answer (score 1):

You issue is that you're not calling your custom function correctly. The function call should have round brackets like this:

```
[create_realtor({properties[1]/property[2]/value[1]})]
```

Always start simple:

- Read through Example 2 below
- Get a simple function working first
- Then build on it and insert your custom logic

https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/inline-php/